# How to force a listing inside a column in overleaf

Tags: formatting

I have the following listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=php]
$post_data = {"image": base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8"), 
"get_img_flg":
True}         
$res = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/detect", json=post_data).json()         
\end{lstlisting}
```

In a 2 column document, but the listing spans to the second column. How can I fix it?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal example instead sniplets, we cannot test this without making assumptions that may not be true for your document

Comment: Besides there is probably not much you can do other than asking listings to break the lines as is explained in the listings manual

Comment: Did you try using `breaklines=true` in the options of `lstlisting`?

Comment: @Skillmonlikestopanswers.xyz that did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

`listings` supports automatic line breaking, but this is by default turned off. You can allow automatic line breaking by specifying the `breaklines` option. So your minimal example would look like the following:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=php,breaklines=true]
$post_data = {"image": base64.b64encode(data).decode("utf-8"), 
"get_img_flg":
True}         
$res = requests.post("http://localhost:8080/detect", json=post_data).json()         
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]